# C# dll import function correctly

Tags: c#, dll, import

I am trying to import a function from a c dll into C#.  The c function looks like this

```
unsigned short write_buffer( unsigned short device_number, unsigned short word_count, unsigned long buffer_link, unsigned short* buffer)
```

my attempt at a C# import looks like this

```
[DllImport("sslib32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern ushort write_buffer(ushort deviceNumber, ushort wordCount, UInt32 bufferLink, IntPtr buffer)
```

In C# i have a  Dictionary of messages that i would like to pass to this function.  The Dictionary looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<ushort>> msgs
```

I am a bit confused how to make a make a proper call to pass msgs as the buffer.  deviceNumber is 2, wordCount is 32, and buffLink is 0.  So i know the call should look something like this

```
write_buffer(2,32,0, msgs[key]);
```

Obviously i am getting an invalid argument for the IntPtr.  What is the proper way to make this call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite unclear what *buffer* should contain and in which direction its data flows.  Your dictionary suggests it should be an array.  Just declare it that way:

```
 private static extern ushort write_buffer(.., ushort[] buffer);
```

And use msgs[key].ToArray() in the call.

Using constants in the write_buffer() call does not make that a likely scenario though, there ought to be msgs[key].Count in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry the question was a bit unclear but the answer you provided seems to be working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate P/Invoke signatures using the P/Invoke Interop Assistant tool that is referenced [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/01/12/p-invoke-signature-generator.aspx).

> In the January 2008 issue of the MSDN
>   Magazine, Yi Zhang and Xiaoying Guo
>   have published a CLR Inside Out column
>   on marshaling between managed and
>   unmanaged code.  In that column, they
>   introduce the P/Invoke Interop
>   Assistant, an automatic GUI and
>   command-line utility for converting
>   between managed and unmanaged
>   signatures (in both directions).  This
>   conversion, of course, is not limited
>   just to Windows signatures; give the
>   tool a snippet of your own C header
>   files and it will dutifully convert
>   them to pretty-printed C#
>   [DllImport]'s.

Comment: It doesn't help here.  That tool can only do a decent job if the C declarations have SAL annotations.  Not available here, no way to tell if this is an array or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind marking the code unsafe, you can simply do:

```
fixed(ushort* pData = msgs[key])
{
    write_buffer(2,32,0, pData);
}
```

And declare your DllImport to take ushort* as the last argument.

The alternative is to use [Marshal.StructureToPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx) to get the array marshalled into fixed memory. This requires you to allocate memory first using [AllocHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cyb68cy.aspx), and freeing using [FreeHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx).